# Ways to build a gate that butts up against neighbors property/house

Tags: fence, gates, gate-post

Here's a picture of the my driveway. I live in the house on the right. [image: driveway]

The left side is my neighbors house. 
I want to build a gate where I've outlined the picture in red.

(Note: my neighbor has a similar driveway on the left side of his house and he built a similar gate and he attached part of the gate to his neighbor's house!)

What are my options for putting the posts for the gate?

Hinge side post:
(1) attach the hinge side post to my neighbor's exterior wall
(2) put the post into a hole in my driveway

Latch side post:
(1) attach to my wall
(2) out post into hole in driveway.

What are the pros/cons of each?
What is sturdier?
What is cheaper?

Comment: Simplest: ask permission to attach the gate to his wall.

Comment: The hinge post is going to be handling all the weight and stress, so no matter which way you go, don't depend on a wall to hold it solidly.

Comment: I would ask the neighbor how he did it and ask if you can do the same. If he is happy with the install he may give you a hand or explain it. People like to think they did a good job and if you use his as an example it may help you get permission.